# Jasmine unit testing angular component that subscribes to a service subject in the constructor gives cannot read property subscribe of undefined

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, rxjs

I am trying to write a test for the component below.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginService } from '../../services/login.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-banner',
  templateUrl: './banner.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./banner.component.css']
})
export class BannerComponent implements OnInit {

  isLoggedIn = false;
  user: User = new User('');

  constructor(
    private loginService: LoginService,
    private router: Router
  ) {
    this.loginService.userWatcher.subscribe(res => {
      this.isLoggedIn = true;
      this.user.oun = res;
    });
  }
...

}
```

However when I write my test I get this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
```

Here is the spec file:

```
import { LoginServiceSpy } from '../../services/mock/login.service.spy.spec';
describe('BannerComponent', () => {
  let component: BannerComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<BannerComponent>;
  const loginService = LoginServiceSpy;
  const user = 'testuser';

  beforeEach(async(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        BannerComponent,
        MockComponent(SpinnerComponent)
      ],
      imports: [
        FormsModule,
        NgbModule.forRoot(),
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: LoginService, useValue: loginService }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BannerComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  describe('Unit Tests', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
      localStorage.setItem('currentUser', user);
      loginService.callNextUserWatcher.and.returnValue(asyncData('test'));
    });
...
```

the following is my login service spy file:

```
import { createSpyFromClass, Spy } from 'jasmine-auto-spies';
import { LoginService } from '../login.service';

export const LoginServiceSpy: Spy<LoginService> = createSpyFromClass(LoginService);
```

I have attempted to try the following in my before each in banner.component.spec.ts:

```
loginService.userWatcher.and.returnValue(Observable.of('test'));
```

with which I get the response from jasmine:
    cannot read property and of undefined

any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because `fixture.detectChanges()` on the outer `beforeEach()` runs first and will load your component. At that time your `spy` was not yet created and hence you are getting that error.

Move your spy to outer `beforeEach()`

```
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BannerComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    loginService.callNextUserWatcher.and.returnValue(asyncData('test')); // spy created before detect change
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

Or do not run `fixture.detectChanges();` from outer `beforeEach()`

```
 beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BannerComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
   // fixture.detectChanges();  -- remove this line
  });
```

First `detectChange` should happen after all your app data is initialized.

Comment: if the spy was not created, the error would be `cannot read userWatcher of undefined` dont you think? The spy was created, the fact that the value of `ùserWatcher` is undefined is a different issue.

Comment: No because he has declared `loginService` at the beginning. But it is not initialized with the spy. That is the issue. `this.loginService` is defined but  `this.loginService.userWatcher` is undefined, so subscribe cannot be read on `userWatcher` which is undefined.

Comment: By spy I meant the value provided though the ValueProvider during the configuration of the TestBed. I think you mean the `ùserWatcher` property.

Comment: Yes, you are probably right here. It took me some time to realize. And also it has nothing to do with the spy that is being created. I guess I have to delete my answer here.

Comment: Any success in finding this out? I tried your suggestion but you are correct and it did not work

Comment: Can you try doing this `{ provide: LoginService, useClass: loginService }`. I am not sure if `LoginServiceSpy` should be considered as a `value` or a `class`.